# Get IP address from ifconfig using PHP

Tags: php, ip, ifconfig

I have the next php code:

```
<?php
   $ip = shell_exec("/sbin/ifconfig  | grep 'inet:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'");
   echo $ip;
?>
```

It works fine when I run it from the command line (`$php5 ip.php`), but when I run it from my browser it shows nothing (`http://localhost/ip.php`).

By the way, I'm trying to print my IP address but whenever I use `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];` I get `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: What OS is this? My Linux box' `ifconfig` lists the IP address labeled with `inet addr:`, not `inet:`.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 10.04 ... but some results appears in Spanish, so 'inet addr:' turns in 'Direcc. inet:'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will work without colon next to 'inet'

```
grep 'inet '
```

Comment: Yes, It works!. But, the regexp get also inet6, how could I get only the inet?

Comment: You could use space at the end of search pattern `grep 'inet '`

Comment: Ok, thanks, it works now. But why my original regexp worked in the command line but no in the browser?

Comment: You might be getting English output from `ifconfig` when running under Apache.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a bash script to do that and execute the bash script. The CLI version of PHP has access to your PATH environment variable, which the Apache module might not have access to.

```
#!/bin/bash

/sbin/ifconfig | grep 'inet:' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'
```

then:

```
<?php

$ip = shell_exec('/path/to/shell/script');
print $ip;

?>
```