# php gethostbyname() function doesn't work in Linux

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

Hi I want to obtain my ip number in php, I'm using ubuntu and apache XAMPP for linux as webserver.

```
<?php 

    echo $gethostname = gethostbyname(gethostname());

?>
```

When I execute the code it returns 127.0.0.1  What I want is like i.e 10.151.32.123.
This code works in windows with xampp, why this code doesn't work in Linux?

Comment: In what situation are you exactly? Do you intend to put this code onto a server eventually? (Your example will most likely work there.) Or do you only want to use it locally for yourself? (Why don't you hard-code the IP then?) Do you have a router between yourself and the public IP `10.151.32.123`, or is it really an IP of your computer? Does [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379922/get-ip-address-from-ifconfig-using-php) help you?

Comment: thanks this is what I need. I just want to do it locally.

Answer (score 0):

It's `gethostname` which is failing you here I think.  Try using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` or `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` in your call to `gethostbyname`.

Comment: I doubt that. Why should `gethostname` fail? My guess is that the host name is mapped to 127.0.0.1 in `/etc/hosts` (that's the default in Ubuntu).

Comment: I replace gethostname with $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] or $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] but no luck, it still returns 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Yeah, in hindsight this was pretty stupid.  Do what @Phillip suggested and check your hosts file.